# .on() not binding to futre elements jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using `.on()` to bind to a button element with a **click** event, it will bind correctly to the elements that are loaded in the present but when new elements are added it won't bind to them any ideas ?

```
$('article#content').on('click', 'button', loadData);

function loadData() {
    var moreTxt = $(this).parent().find('section.hidden')
    var txt = moreTxt.is(':visible') ? 'Read More' : 'Hide';
    $(this).text(txt);
    moreTxt.slideToggle('slow');
}
```

JsFiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/jRtMc/

Comment: Could you please provide this example in jsfiddle?

Comment: So `article#content` exists at the time the code is executed, and the button is being loaded later?

Comment: a fiddle or your mark-up would help

Comment: adding a jsfiddle now and @j08691, no the button is loaded at the same time

Comment: One thing I would recommend is to change your selector. Unless you have multiple elements with the same id "#content" (bad practice anyway) then "article" isn't necessary.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jRtMc/

Comment: What's the fiddle not doing that you want it to do? Seems to work fine.

Comment: Seem to be working to me. http://jsfiddle.net/jRtMc/1/

Comment: @iGanja i can't remove the "article" from the selector as it wont find the elements

Comment: and i know it works but not if the element is added in the future, i forgot to add that to the fiddle one second

Comment: If article is dynamically loaded, try `$(document).on('click', '#content button', loadData);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate form of `.on()` allows you to attach a handler to some parent element which will always exist, and then filter events against where the click originates.  This allows you to set a handler once, and not worry about whether you have attached it to new objects or not.

In this form, the element(s) you call `.on()` for must not be deleted after you attach the handler.  In your case `$('article#content')` must exist when you call `on()`, must be a parent of the `button` you care about (which may or may not exist), and must not be deleted/created/recreated after you call `.on()`.

I suspect that your `#content` is being dynamically generated.  (If not, you have other issues, because your button is referencing `.parent()`, which will always be `#content`)  If `article` is dynamic, you need to attach the handler to a permanent parent.  You can always use `body`, but it is **very heavy-handed**, as any click in body will have to be filtered through this handler.  Additionally, you can't have more than one of the same id, so you need to use a class (`.content`), instead:

```
$('body').on('click', '.content button', loadData);
```

Instead, find a permanent parent and use that:

```
$('#ParentOfArticles').on('click', '.content button', loadData);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HrE6J/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have multiple articles contents in your page, so you mustn't identify them with the same id. You should create a `content` class and then select them.

```
$('article.content').on('click', 'button', loadData);
```

Comment: Good catch.  However, I suspect the OP has a combination of issues.  Interestingly, even if there is an illegal duplicate ID, if the handler is attached to a parent, the filter should still work correctly.  But in the form the OP uses, it will only attach to the first `#content`.